# Query to check whether table is journaled in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

I am new to db2.
Is there a query to check whether a table is journaled in DB2 or not. if it is journaled what is the name of the journal.

I found this query: Find all journals in library MJATST.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (QSYS2.OBJECT_STATISTICS('MJATST ','JRN') ) AS X
```

but i couldn't find something similar to tables in schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **DSPFD** command for the file(table).. It specifics bunch of info about the file(table)..

**MBJRNL** -(N/Y) whether table has journal associated with it

if Y then you can get journal info from following column else this column will be null

**MBJRNM**  - Journal Name

**MBJRLB** - Journal Schema

hope this helps anyone looking for something similar!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any and a quick search of the likely catalogs didn't turn up a way.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm

The journal information is available in the Retrieve Object Description (QUSROBJD) API
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/qusrobjd.htm

You could wrap that API in a UDF.

Comment: If the API is unfamiliar, the RTVOBJD command can also return journal status and journal name.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a CLLE source that can be used at least as far back as v5r3 [no advantage is taken of newer CL support to make the code more succinct] to create a bound ILE CL *PGM object that is invoked as a scalar function [as was previously] defined to the SQL by the CREATE FUNCTION shown in the block comments preceding the CL source; a very simple test-suite verified the functionality:

```
 /* create function jrnOfDBF                            */
 /* ( table_name varchar(128)                           */
 /* , table_libr varchar( 10)                           */
 /* ) returns char(20)                                  */
 /* language PLI -- a lie to allow VARCHAR inputs       */
 /* specific        jrnOfDBF                            */
 /* not deterministic                                   */
 /* no sql  returns null on null input                  */
 /* disallow parallel  not fenced no external action    */
 /* parameter style SQL                                 */
 /* external name   jrnOfDBF                            */
 /* */
 /* CRTBNDCL PGM(JRNOFDBF) SRCMBR(..following_source..) */
 /* */
 pgm (&tblnam &tbllib +                                   
      &rtnval &rtnind &sqlste &udfnam &specnm &diagmg)    
 dcl &tblnam *char 130                                    
 dcl &tbllib *char  12                                    
 dcl &rtnval *char  20                                    
 dcl &rtnind *int    2                                    
 dcl &sqlste *char   5                                    
 dcl &udfnam *char 141                                    
 dcl &specnm *char 130                                    
 dcl &diagmg *char  72                                    
 /* Pgm Vars */                                           
 dcl &lngnam *char 128                    
 dcl &lnglib *char  10                    
 dcl &dbflib *char  10                    
 dcl &dbfobj *char  10                    
 dcl &jrnsts *char   1                    
 dcl &jrnlib *char  10                    
 dcl &jrnobj *char  10                    
 dcl &strlen *int    4                    
 dcl &qualnm *char  20                    
 monmsg cpf0000 exec(goto badthing)       
 main:                                    
  chgvar &strlen (%bin(&tbllib 1 2))      
  chgvar &lnglib (%sst(&tbllib 3 &strlen))
  chgvar &strlen (%bin(&tblnam 1 2))      
  chgvar &lngnam (%sst(&tblnam 3 &strlen))
  call qdbrtvsn (&qualnm &lngnam &strlen &lnglib x'0000000000000000') 
   /* 1  Qualified object name              Output   Char( 20)      */
   /* 2  Long object name                   Input    Char(128)      */
   /* 3  Length of long object name         Input    Binary(4)      */
   /* 4  Library name                       Input    Char( 10)      */
   /* 5  Error code                         I/O      Char( * )      */
  chgvar  &dbflib (%sst(&qualnm 11 10))                               
  chgvar  &dbfobj (%sst(&qualnm 01 10))                               
  rtvobjd &dbflib/&dbfobj *file aspdev(*) +                           
     jrnsts(&jrnsts) jrn(&jrnobj) jrnlib(&jrnlib)                     
  if (&jrnsts *eq '1') then(do)                                       
   chgvar &rtnval (&jrnobj *cat &jrnlib) /* qualified name of jrn */  
  enddo                                                               
  /* else &rtnval is already blanks */                                
  chgvar &rtnind 0                                                    
 mainend:                                                             
  return                                                              
 badthing:                                                            
  chgvar &rtnind -1                                                   
  chgvar &sqlste 'JRN99'                                              
  chgvar &diagmg 'Unable to retrieve Obj Info; see joblog'            
  sndpgmmsg *n cpf9898 qcpfmsg &diagmg tomsgq(*topgmq) topgmq(*prv) + 
     msgtype(*diag)                                                   
  goto mainend                                                        
 endpgm
```

An example invocation of the function:

```
 select jrnOfDBF('SYSROUTINES', 'QSYS2') from qsys2.qsqptabl
```

What the interactive Start SQL (STRSQL) display report would show:

```
 ....+....1....+....2           
 JRNOFDBF                       
 QSQJRN    QSYS2                
 ********  End of data  ********
```

Note: The value of blanks being returned is indicative of either *currently not journaled* **or** *never journaled*, whereas any non-blank value should be the qualified-name of the journal in the standard form of: `'10bytObjNm10bytLibNm'`